# cdi observe session scoped bean changed

Tags: java, cdi, observable

i'm trying to observes a @SessionScoped component after change any property. HttpSessionAttributeListener not fire changes in cdi managed components.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@SessionScoped
public class TestSession implements Serializable {


private User user;

public TestSession() {

}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

}
```

An example Servlet:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(name = "demo", urlPatterns = "/demo")
public class DemoServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoServlet.class);

@Inject
private TestSession testSession;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    User user = new User(1L,new Role(1L));
    user.setId(RandomUtils.nextLong());
    testSession.setUser(user); //listen that component change something


    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/demo.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

}

Is the a way to listen when component change any attribute ? Anyone has some approach to do that ?

Important : I dont have access to rewrite or add code on TestSession java class or servlet .

Comment: Your classes are in the same war as TestSession and Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

You can place an [interceptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/interceptors.htm#GKEED) in the setUser() method that creates an [event](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv005.htm#GKHIC) then catch it.

Comment: I cant not interact with this class , its thirdy part class

Comment: CDI, Interceptors and Events are parte of the JavaEE container. Are you using a JavaEE container or are you just using CDI as a dependency? In the second case you'll need to include them in your project

Comment: I`m using java ee container . I mean that i cant not interact with TestSession class (rewrite or add annotations,etc)

Comment: Then, since it's not a final class, maybe if you can create a subclass of it, overriding the setter, placing the interceptor on it, and injecting an instance of your newly created class in the context you expect to produce that change in the expected attribute. That solution is not likely to fit in your problem, but I can't think of any other way.